# ValidationException: addHeader: Invalid input

Tags: esapi

Hello I have upgraded ESAPI libraries from 2.1 to 2.5.2 version and I am getting the following error in the new version which was working in the old version.Any help is appreciated.
Invalid input:
context=addHeader, type(HTTPHeaderValue)=^[a-zA-Z0-9()-=*.?;,+/:&_ ]*$, input=attachment;filename="CstmUpdFile-I_3.3.3
647_20230822213220.ZIP"
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException: addHeader: Invalid input.
Please conform to regex ^[a-zA-Z0-9()-=*.?;,+/:&_ ]*$ with a maximum length of 4096
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.checkWhitelist(StringValidationRule.java:140)

Invalid input:
context=addHeader, type(HTTPHeaderValue)=^[a-zA-Z0-9()-=*.?;,+/:&_ ]*$, input=attachment;filename="CstmUpdFile-I_3.3.3
647_20230822213220.ZIP"
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException: addHeader: Invalid input.
Please conform to regex ^[a-zA-Z0-9()-=*.?;,+/:&_ ]*$ with a maximum length of 4096
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.checkWhitelist(StringValidationRule.java:140)

Answer (score 0):

After fixing a small bug in the regex:

[image]

escape the equals sign to get past that.  `^[a-zA-Z0-9()\\\-=\\*\\.\\?;,+\\/:&_ ]*$`

The match fails because your input has quotes.

`attachment;filename="CstmUpdFile-I_3.3.3 647_20230822213220.ZIP"`

The regex clearly doesn't match.  See debug output:

[image]

I did a diff between the regex 2.1 to present day and there has been no change to the regex.

[image]

You DID find a bug in our regex, so THAT is good, but I would say that THAT particular input working  in 2.1 seems impossible.  Any input with a quotation mark should fail here.  I just tried an input of a single `\"` and it fails.  I would suggest maybe percent-escaping any input that needs to be sent in an HTTP header.